# Path or line conditions

Tags: qgis

I want to create a path\line between 2 points but i don't want a straight line. I need a line with conditions, for example avoid going trough buildings.

How do I create a line\path between 2 point\coordinates with conditions? I want to create a line like in the first image where the line avoids buildings. I know I can connect 2 points with a line but that would look like the second image.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Only one line? Draw it manually

Comment: yes only 1 line. But I just started with my project. I eventually want to create multiple lines automatically with conditions. But I want to start easy and try it with 1 line first. I want to create a district heat network within QGIS.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. OK, if you don't give us more information and details about **what exactly** you want to do, it's impossible to give any advice than just: "OK, than create the line with the conditions you wish": what should be avoided and how (whicht distance), based on what conditions etc. etc. We don't know you project and intentions, so please edit the quesiton to add more details - and ideally, add a screenshot showing how the final result should look like.

Comment: Better now? I want QGIS to create a line between 2 points with certain conditions. In this case I want the line to avoid buildings.

Comment: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/basic_network_analysis.html

Comment: Here are few options. You can use Google maps API or Open Street Maps API. If you own all the points data, then you can write your own Dijkstra or any other shortest path algorithm to build the path.

Comment: thanks. Now I am wondering if I can direct the point to point line through a grassfield and not only a street?

Comment: Do you have all the data with you like streets(lines) etc?

Comment: consider performing a `least cost path` analysis

Comment: I have all the streets as linestring file

Comment: I am sure then all those streets would not be passing through a building or grassfield. Just use some shortest path algorithms if you have expertise into that area or if it is just for your analysis, QGIS has nice network analysis tools under toolbox which you could utilize. If you want to analyze through some scripts, try to use pgrouting by loading the data into postgres and appropriate preparation of data.